# find every combination of elements in a column of a dataframe, which add up to a given sum in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to ease my life by writing a menu creator, which is supposed to permutate a weekly menu from a list of my favourite dishes, in order to get a little bit more variety in my life.
I gave every dish a value of how many days it approximately lasts and tried to arrange the dishes to end up with menus worth 7 days of food.

I've already tried solutions for knapsack functions from here, including dynamic programming, but I'm not experienced enough to get the hang of it. This is because all of these solutions are targeting only the most efficient option and not every combination, which fills the Knapsack.

```
library(adagio)
#create some data
dish <-c('Schnitzel','Burger','Steak','Salad','Falafel','Salmon','Mashed potatoes','MacnCheese','Hot Dogs')
days_the_food_lasts <- c(2,2,1,1,3,1,2,2,4)
price_of_the_food <- c(20,20,40,10,15,18,10,15,15)
data <- data.frame(dish,days_the_food_lasts,price_of_the_food)

#give each dish a distinct id
data$rownumber <- (1:nrow(data))

#set limit for how many days should be covered with the dishes
food_needed_for_days <- 7

#knapsack function of the adagio library as an example, but all other solutions I found to the knapsackproblem were the same
most_exspensive_food <- knapsack(days_the_food_lasts,price_of_the_food,food_needed_for_days)
data[data$rownumber %in% most_exspensive_food$indices, ]

#output
dish days_the_food_lasts price_of_the_food rownumber
1 Schnitzel                   2                20         1
2    Burger                   2                20         2
3     Steak                   1                40         3
4     Salad                   1                10         4
6    Salmon                   1                18         6
```

Simplified:

I need a solution to a single objective single Knapsack problem, which returns all possible combinations of dishes which add up to 7 days of food.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: If you only have 9 foods then there are only 2^9 = 512 possible subsets so you could enumerate them all and filter out the ones wanted.

Comment: This is generally a good idea, but this is but a small reproducible example. My original set is about 100 dishes long and growing. R won't even let me calculate these subsets with just numbers as the vector would be to long. Anyways, it would also cost too much computing power as it would subset every nonsense subset as well. e.g. for no food or for a 100 dishes as well.